# How to get socket client for a user?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm implementing a node.js server that manages bi-connections between users with socket.io (version:0.8.7). I use an array that stores the users that have no chat partners yet. When a user requests a new partner, the app picks a user in this array and then checks to see if the user is still connected. And here's my problem:

I can't manage to get the socket client for the user, even if the user is still connected. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
// An array of users that do not have a chat partner
var soloUsers = [];

var io = sio.listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {


    socket.on('sessionStart', function (message) 
    {       
        // Parse the incoming event
        switch (message.event) {

            // User requested initialization data
            case 'initial':
                ...

        // User requested next partner
        case 'next':

        // Create a "user" data object for me
        var me = {
            sessionId: message.data.sessionId,
            clientId: socket.sessionid
        };

        var partner;
        var partnerClient;

        // Look for a user to partner with in the list of solo users
        for (var i = 0; i < soloUsers.length; i++) 
        {
            var tmpUser = soloUsers[i];

            // Make sure our last partner is not our new partner
            if (socket.partner != tmpUser) 
            {
                // Get the socket client for this user
                partnerClient = io.sockets.clientsIndex[tmpUser.clientId];

                // Remove the partner we found from the list of solo users
                soloUsers.splice(i, 1);

                // If the user we found exists...
                if (partnerClient) 
                {
                    // Set as our partner and quit the loop today
                    partner = tmpUser;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        ...
```

I get the following error:

```
partnerClient = io.sockets.clientsIndex[clientId];
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
```

I did an output (console.log) of the clientId, and it is definitely indefined. Furthermore, I think the API might have changed in socket.io version 0.8, and you can't use the "clientsIndex" method anymore. Does anyone know the replacement?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with partnerClient?

Comment: I want to be sure the partner is still connected before assigning him to the user.

Comment: I've added an answer while you were editing the post. By the way, looping through an array of clients isn't that good, imagine how slow that would be if you had 10.000 clients for example. That would block the Node.js event loop.

Comment: You're quite right. But the loop stops once it finds a new user, so the loop won't last more than 2 iterations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best thing to do is to keep track of the connected clients in an object. Here's how I would achieve this:

```
var clients = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // remember the client by associating the socket.id with the socket
  clients[socket.id] = socket; 
  socket.on('sessionStart', function (message) {
    // get the socket.id of the partner on each message
    var partner = message.from; 
    if (clients[partner]) {
      // check if the partner exists and send a message to the user
      clients[socket.id].emit('message', { from: partner, msg: message });
    }
  }

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    delete clients[socket.id]; // delete the client from the list
  });
}
```

Note: In a real production application you would normally check for the session data and associate each client with a username and a socket.id.